# Server-side (Isomorphic) DOM maniuplation Node.js + Cheerio

Tags: reactjs, server-side, cheerio, isomorphic-javascript

I am writing an Isomorphic react application and I am running into server-side render errors such as `document.querySelector is not a function` or  `target.addEventListener is not a function` when using certain external libraries.

From research, I gather that Cheerio is the best option for DOM manipulation on the server in NodeJS however figuring out correct implementation remains a problem.

Is Cheerio the right library to use and if so, how would I go about implementing this in my application?

Comment: I can understand you want querySelector, but I can't imagine how addEventListener could make sense on the server.

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know it is not possible to run those commands from server side, those will need to be handle on clients side instead.

Best

Comment: Doesn't this link (https://maxogden.com/scraping-with-node.html) seem to suggest the opposite?

Comment: What would you suggest is the best way to get around these errors from your experience?

Comment: Based on the cheerio documentation the document object is not listed check the API documentation at https://cheerio.js.org/  or https://www.npmjs.com/package/cheerio#readme

Comment: Instead of document.querySelector try to use the selector method from cheeiro, Selectors

Cheerio's selector implementation is nearly identical to jQuery's, so the API is very similar.

$( selector, [context], [root] )

selector searches within the context scope which searches within the root scope. selector and context can be an string expression, DOM Element, array of DOM elements, or cheerio object. root is typically the HTML document string.

Comment: Sounds good but the code that needs altering is part of an external library - that's why I was thinking maybe I could use Cheerio as a more global solution e.g. integrate it somewhere within my app so that any future server-side DOM manipulation would be dealt with globally rather than on a case-by-case basis. Do you think this possible?

Comment: Based on the documentation Cheerio is another HTML parser, here are a list of some popular HTML parsers https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_HTML_parsers, Then on server side you can model your HTML to deliver to the client side, but I understand that this HTML will not be rendered in the server side, that HTML will be rendered in the browser.